# Predicting the direction of moving a object in R

Tags: r, machine-learning

I am trying to produce a model that classify the direction of a moving object. In the figure we see a single projection of 3D space where an object was moved up and down (red) vs up and down together with left and right (blue).

I thought the best and easiest way in to produce 2 linear models A and B and use that to predict. My problem is that I am not sure which method to use. I have tried the following, does it make sense?

```
modFitlm <- train(z ~ x+class, method="lm", data=updown)
```

However, the outcome should be A or B rather than z and I am not sure how to tackle this problem.

[image]

I have also tried Rpart since it seems the best model and got 80% accuracy.
decision tree is also shown:

[image]

Comment: You also can try logistic regression since it works as a binary classification.

Comment: Support vector machine would be good for this too

Answer (score 2):

Support vector machine would be good for this.  Logistic regression won't be great since it's a linear classifier, and your data do not look separable by a line without a lot of error.

This kind of looks like the XOR problem, which support vector machine with a polynomial kernal does very well at.

[image]

This should be easy to implement in R and I'm quite sure you will do much better than 80% accuracy.

See more about SVM in R here: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/e1071/vignettes/svmdoc.pdf